# Disable copy / paste locally (browser, extension, etc.)

Tags: windows, web-browser, kiosk, copy-paste

For security reasons, I would like to disable copy and paste in the web browser, of a computer that we're going to make publicly available in my work place.

I've seen that, in some computers placed in public places, copy and paste is disabled. I would like to achieve this using an extension, some hidden setting, or an alternative browser.

What would be the best way?

Thanks!

Comment: Whatever you do, also make sure Flash and Java are not installed.

Comment: You also need to disable the "print screen" button.

Comment: The browser should run fullscreen, without any way to exit fullscreen, I guess?

Comment: This is generally done by JavaScript, but is trivial to get around. I press `ctrl + U` or `f12` to view the page source code, save it, remove the check and load the new page back into the browser. You can deter casual use, but nothing is ever completely safe.

Comment: @SteveBarnes and the `file` menu? Save/save as/print ...

Comment: Search SourceForge, or Google around, and learn about `kiosk mode`

Comment: You don't tell us if you want to prevent this only on pages over which you have full control (which seems likely), or on all pages (which seems silly)

Comment: "Security" against what? What do you want to secure, exactly? The host shared computer? The person using it? What are your exact goals?

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the content, i.e. is Java required, etc., you could use something like the [wxPython](https://wxpython.org/) HTML2_Webview - with a couple of adjustments to the code in the demo from the [Docs & Demo](https://wxpython.org/download.php) package you could make it full screen and modal, with no menu or your own menus, without a close button & you could trap key presses to disallow ctrl-P, ctrl-C & print screen operations *there is a section in the demo on capturing the keyboard as well*.  You could also capture exit events to prompt for a maintainers password.

### Pros:

- Quick to develop almost all of the code that you need is in the demo package
- Small - the [demo](https://github.com/wxWidgets/wxPython/blob/master/demo/HTML2_WebView.py) is less than 155 lines of code including blanks and comments.
- Runs on Windows, OS-X & Linux *once you have your application it will also run on any of them without changes*
- Lots of online help, books, etc.
- Free, Gratis & Open Source but with commercial use allowed.

### Cons

- A little bit to learn
- No Java support but you can use the full power of HTML, CSS & at least some Javascript.
- Supported facilities varies a little between platforms.
- No Flash Player or Active X support.

### The Demo

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Cara,

I am unable to answer your question entirely, but have a few suggestions.

**Internet Explorer**

Run `inetcpl.cpl` and then follow:

1. Go to `Tools` then `Internet Options`.
2. Go to `Security tab`.
3. Select `Internet zone`, then click on `Custom level…` button.
4. Find the `Scripting` section
5. Under `Allow Programmatic clipboard access` option and select `Disable`

This will not restrict access to copy and paste, but will disable scripts that access the clipboard.

You can probably use the following VBS to prevent the paste in IE option:

`Set objIE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application") 
objIE.Navigate("about:blank") 
l=0 
DO 
objIE.document.parentwindow.clipboardData.SetData "text", "" 
Loop until (l>1)`

**Firefox**

Open the advanced options (`about:config`) in Firefox and locate
`dom.event.clipboardevents.enable` and set this to `false`.

Supposedly, AdBlockPlus disables/prevents clipboard manipulation in browsers, so you can try GoogleChrome with Clipboard [here](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/adblock-plus/cfhdojbkjhnklbpkdaibdccddilifddb).

You can have a [look at](http://www.techgainer.com/how-to-disable-copy-cut-past-function-in-your-windows/) `agent.exe`, it seems to restrict the mouse function of copy and paste - others such as [Stopper and Prevent are also available](https://www.raymond.cc/blog/disable-files-folders-and-text-from-being-copied-or-moved-in-windows/2/).